# Swift type-variable to generic-type-variable

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, types, casting

The error I get is unsurprising, but how would I accomplish something like this in Swift?

```
let stringType = String.self
let stringArrayType = Array<String>.self
let stringArrayTypeFromVariable = Array<stringType>.self // Error :Use of undeclared type 'stringType'
```

My final goal is to build a function like this.

```
print( getTypeAsArray( Int.self ) ) // prints "Array<Int>.Type"
print( getTypeAsArray( String.self ) ) // prints "Array<String>.Type"
```

Here's my current attempt. It doesn't compile, but I think maybe this is solvable with generics like this.

```
// this version doesn't compile...
func getTypeAsArray<T>(_ value: T) -> [T].Type {
    return []
}
getTypeAsArray(String.self)

// this version compiles, but doesn't give me the functionality I want...The expected output was Array<String>, not Array<String.Type>
func getTypeAsArray<T>(_ value: T) -> [T].Type {
    return type(of: [])
}
getTypeAsArray(String.self) // -> Array<String.Type>
```

Comment: Your final goal seems kind of pointless. Is there a _final_ final goal? Are you going to pass in types unknown at compile time into `getTypeAsArray`?

Comment: @Sweeper I need it at runtime, not compile time. But you're right, if I were needing this for compile time it would be pointless.

Comment: Okay, I don't think this is possible then. What would the function signature look like? It would accept a `Any.Type` parameter, right? What type would it return?

Comment: @Sweeper I was thinking about using generics in the signature to pull it off. I updated the question with my current attempt

Comment: Generics are bound at compile-time. If you don't know the type at compile time, generics won't help. Continuing on with my previous argument, the method would need to accept a parameter `t` of type `Any.Type`. This is so that at runtime, `t` could store any meta type object. But what would the method return? It can't return `[Any].Type`, because metatypes are not covariant.

Comment: I see your point. There not way to have it return [T].Type and have T determined dynamically because T must be determined at compile time

Comment: I see that you are even struggling with a "compile-time only" version of `getTypeAsArray`. You probably meant `func getTypeAsArray<T>(_ value: T.Type) -> [T].Type { return [T].self }`.

Comment: I think I just solved it

Comment: Yeah I actually got something like a solution of yours working right as you commented haha

Comment: Yeah yours works perfectly. Nicely done. Do you want to put that in the answers? Or I can write it up. It would be helpful for someone else if they ever need this

Comment: @Sweeper So now I'm onto another problem. I want to generalize it so that I can pass `Array.self` of `Set.self` or any other type that has a generic. So I would want a function like `getTypeAsGenericOfAnotherType(String.self, Set.self)` would give me `Set<String>`

Comment: @joehinkle11 Don't drink too much of the generic juice. It'll make you loopy. Swift is a staticly type language, for the most part. There's almost nothing that you can do with an `Any`, besides passing it around, or casting it down to a narrower type (which allows you to call functions/properties of that type). Resolving types at runtime doesn't achieve anything for you, because your code is checked statically. Given `x: Any`, you can't do `x.foo()`, even if you resolve `x` at runtime to be a `Fooable` object.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica good advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your final goal by doing something like this:

```
func getTypeAsArray<T>(_ value: T.Type) -> [T].Type { 
    return [T].self 
}
```

But this won't work in situations like this:

```
let t: UIView.Type = UITableView.self
print(getTypeAsArray(t))
```

You'd expect it to print `Array<UITableView>`, but it prints `Array<UIView>`.

Unfortunately, I don't think the you can make the above case work as well. Because such a method must accept an `Any.Type`, but what would its return type be? It can't return a `[Any].Type` because although metatypes are covariant, metatype *arrays* are not:

```
let t: [UIView].Type = [UITableView].self
```

> error: cannot convert value of type `[UIView].Type` to specified type `[UITableView].Type`

Comment: This works for me because in my project I'm already downcasting before passing it through. Thank you!